# String won't return

Tags: java

The method `getResponseToCorrectAnswer` and `getResponseToIncorrectAnswer` won't return any strings, but a print will work, so it's getting to the method. Does anyone know how to get these two methods to correctly return a `String`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CAI {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer;

    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){    
        int num1 = generateRandomSingleDigitNumber();
        int num2 = generateRandomSingleDigitNumber();
        generateMultiplicationQuestion(num1, num2);
        answer = input.nextInt();
        validateMultiplicationAnswer(num1, num2, answer);
    }//end for

}//end main

public static void generateMultiplicationQuestion(int num1, int num2){

    System.out.println("What is the product of " + num1 + " x " + num2 + "?");

}//end generateMultiplicationQuestion

public static int generateRandomSingleDigitNumber(){

    return (int)(Math.random()*10);

}//end generateRandomSingleDigitNumber

public static String getResponseToCorrectAnswer(){
    //return ("Correct");

    int num;
    num = (int)(Math.random()*4);
    if(num == 3){
        return("Very good");
    }else if(num == 2){
        return("Excellent!");
    }else if(num == 1){
        return("Nice work!");
    }else{
        return("Keep up the good work!");
    }//end if 

}//end getResponseToCorrectAnswer

public static String getResponseToIncorrectAnswer(){

    int num;
    num = (int)(Math.random()*4);
    if(num == 3){
        return("No. Please try again.");
    }else if(num == 2){
        return("Wrong. Try once more");
    }else if(num == 1){
        return("Don't give up. Keep trying.");
    }else{
        return("Incorrect. Please answer again.");
    }//end if

}//end getResponseToIncorrectAnswer

public static boolean validateMultiplicationAnswer(int num1, int num2, int answer) {

    if(answer == num1 * num2){
        getResponseToCorrectAnswer();
        return true;
    }else{
        getResponseToIncorrectAnswer();
        return false;
    }//end if

}//end validateMultiplicationAnswer

}//end class
```

Comment: Why do you think those methods don't return any strings?  It looks to me like they do, even though you're not using the returned values for anything.

Answer (score 3):

> the method getResponseToCorrectAnswer and getResponseToIncorrectAnswer won't return any strings

Sure it will, but you're not assigning the string to anything so you don't see it.

Try this

```
String response = getResponseToCorrectAnswer();
System.out.println(response);
```

and you will see that response holds the return value.